# self.context.click is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm currently working on an barcode scanner project in ionic 2 and had a question about the "self.context.click is not a function" error.

The HTML button:

```
<button btn-green block large (click)="click()">
  <p>Scan uw tafel</p>
</button>
```

The TS function:

```
click() {
    BarcodeScanner.scan()
      .then((result) => {
        if (!result.cancelled) {
          const barcodeData = new BarcodeData(result.text, result.format);
          this.scanDetails(barcodeData);
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err);
      })
  }
```

The Error:

```
app.bundle.js:44353 EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/scan/scan.html:4:34BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
app.bundle.js:44353 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.click is not a functionBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
app.bundle.js:44353 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
app.bundle.js:44353 TypeError: self.context.click is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_ScanPage0._handle_click_4_0 (ScanPage.template.js:141:28)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:32126:24
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:45573:36
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:45659:111
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37493:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:230:48)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37526:78)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37422:73)BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
app.bundle.js:44353 ERROR CONTEXT:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
app.bundle.js:44353 DebugContextBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ app.bundle.js:44353
zone.js:260 Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/scan/scan.html:4:34
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: self.context.click is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: self.context.click is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_ScanPage0._handle_click_4_0 (ScanPage.template.js:141:28)
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:32126:24
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:45573:36
    at http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:45659:111
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:323:29)
    at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37493:41)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:322:35)
    at Zone.runGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/zone.js:230:48)
    at NgZoneImpl.runInnerGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37526:78)
    at NgZone.runGuarded (http://localhost:8100/build/js/app.bundle.js:37422:73)
ERROR CONTEXT:
[object Object]
```

This is from a tutorial and it worked in the test files i made. Now i want to implement it my own project and i get this error as soon as i click the button to scan the page.

I hope somebody can help, couldn't find much online about this subject.

Comment: have you tried to set `click()` public?

Comment: change the name of the method, instead of `click` use `scan` or something like that `(click)="scan()"`

Comment: @Supamiu in TS if modifier is omitted it is public by default